# Why can't I compare a count of a new array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, nsarray

Can someone explain this to me ?

```
if(0 <= -1)
    NSLog(@"Thank god");
if([NSArray new].count <= -1)
    NSLog(@"What the **** ? %i", [NSArray new].count);
if([[NSArray alloc] init].count <= -1)
    NSLog(@"What the **** ? %i", [[NSArray alloc] init].count );
```

Output is twice `What the **** ? 0` and I was expecting no output I expect to have 0 as count.

If I put the count in a int or log it it ouputs 0 (zero), but the if statement generates a true on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is you are comparing a unsigned integer to signed integer.

Little more detail. If you compare an unsigned integer to an signed integer the signed integer will be interpreted as unsigned integer. So you signed value of -1 will be intepreted as 4294967295.

Comment: gives warning if try to compare signed integer with unsigned.

Comment: @AniketKote what are you talking about, i didn't post any code

Comment: Great. The little detail was something I was wondering about. But I still don't get why a unsigned count will be returned if there are 0 values in an array and a signed count will if there are > 0 items. Why don't just return the same type in both cases?

Comment: count always returns an unsigned integer (methods in objective-c, as in c always return the same type).

Answer (score 0):

```
signed int i=-1;

    if(0 <= i)
        NSLog(@"Thank god");
    if([NSArray new].count <= i)
        NSLog(@"What the **** ? %i", [NSArray new].count);
    else if([[NSArray alloc] init].count <= i)
        NSLog(@"What the **** ? %i", [[NSArray alloc] init].count );

Try this.
```

Comment: where is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

This one

```
NSLog(@"%u", -1);
```

outputs `4294967295` and 0 <= 4294967295 is true.

Instead of testing for lower equals -1 try to test lower zero. It's the same. But XCode says `Comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false` so you have to do this test